# 400 Bad Request, RESTTEMPLATE

Tags: java, android, spring

Использую android устройство и сервер на spring mvc + maven 
Пытаюсь выслать данные + файл на сервер при помощи RestTeamplate. С просто данными все красиво вышло, а вот с файлом проблемы. 
Руководствуюсь [вот этим туториалом](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples/blob/master/spring-android-showcase/client/src/org/springframework/android/showcase/rest/HttpPostFormDataActivity.java)

Клиент:

```
protected AnotherPostDTO doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("res/drawable/bbb.png");
    formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    formData.add("owners_id", "1");
    formData.add("file", resource);

    try {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(formData, requestHeaders);

        ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>(Arrays.asList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(), new FormHttpMessageConverter()));
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(converters);

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

        return restTemplate.postForObject(Constants.URLs.UPLOAD_FILE, requestEntity, AnotherPostDTO.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return post;
}
```

Сервер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data")
public @ResponseBody ImgPost handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("owners_id") String owners_id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("file upload");
    ImgPost post = new ImgPost();
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            bytes = file.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error processing uploaded file");
        }
        return post; //ok
    } else {
        return post;//fail
    }
}
```

Бин:

```
@Bean
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("128KB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("128KB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

Ошибка у клиента:

```
W/RestTemplate: POST request for "http://192.168.0.250:8081/server/upload" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
 E/ContentValues: 400 Bad Request org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
```